# Looking for patterns in a string how to?

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to find all instances of the substring `EnemyType('XXXX')` where XXXX is an arbitrary string and the instasnce of `EnemyType('XXXX')` can appear multiple times.

Right now I'm using a consortium of `index of`/`substring` functions in C# but would like to know if there's a cleaner way of doing it?

Comment: What do you want to do next with the `EnemyType('XXXX')` string?

Comment: Include the current code if possible, And what is wrong with the current code

Comment: @DestinationN I just want to know what the XXXXXXX's are inside EnemyType for file parsing purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regex. Example:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

var inputString = "   EnemyType('1234')abcdeEnemyType('5678')xyz";
var regex = new Regex(@"EnemyType\('\d{4}'\)");

var matches = regex.Matches(inputString);

foreach (Match i in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i.Value);
}
```

It will print:

```
EnemyType('1234')
EnemyType('5678')
```

The pattern to match is `@"EnemyType\('\d{4}'\)"`, where `\d{4}` means 4 numeric characters `(0-9)`. The parentheses are escaped with backslash.

**Edit**: Since you only want the string inside quotes, not the whole string, you can use named groups instead.

```
var inputString = "   EnemyType('1234')abcdeEnemyType('5678')xyz";
var regex = new Regex(@"EnemyType\('(?<id>[^']+)'\)");

var matches = regex.Matches(inputString);

foreach (Match i in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i.Groups["id"].Value);
}
```

Now it prints:

```
1234
5678
```

Regex is a really nice tool for parsing strings. If you often parse strings, regex can make life so much easier.

Comment: What about cases of Enemytype('XXXXXX') (i.e. there are mo than 4 characters in the string)

Comment: `\d{n}` where n can be any number. This means it should match at least n number of numeric characters. If you don't know how many, you can use `\d+` instead, where it means at least 1 numeric character.

Comment: You can see more under the section "Limiting Repetition"  in this [link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

Comment: Note that `\d` matches any character defined as numeric by the Unicode standard. That includes, for example, the Japanese numeric characters and other language-specific numbers. If you want just the digits 0-9, then you'd replace the `\d+` with `[0-9]+`.

Comment: Also, the OP's question didn't specify that the XXXXX was limited to numerics. It says, "where XXXX is an arbitrary string". So you'll probably want `[^']+` to replace the `\d+`.

Comment: @JimMischel That makes sense. Will edit my answer now.